# Не отображаются изображения в OpenCart после разворачивания на локальком сервере

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, opencart, symlinks

Хотел развернуть копию сайта на локалке, все отображается, кроме изображений товаров. Изображения не видны ни в админке, ни на сайте. При этом, если я скопирую часть пути с оригинального сайта и пропишу в путь локального - все отображается (даже с учетом кириллицы и пробелов).

PHP 5.6, OpenCart 2.3.0.2.2 (из файла index.php), Apache 2. Имена файлов "кривые": на русском, с пробелами в начале имени, расширения и маленькими и большими буквами. Но на реальном сервере все работает!

С OpenCart'ом на Вы. Подходящих решений не нашел, хотя упоминаются замечания, которые есть на сайте (русские буквы, пробелы).

Права на все файлы и папки 777 (пробовал и 700 и 600 для файлов), владелец www-data.

Конфиг /admin/config.php:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://website.ocart/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://website.ocart/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://website.ocart/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://website.ocart/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/system/storage/upload/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/catalog/');
```

Второй конфиг (config.php):

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://website.ocart/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://website.ocart/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/website/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/website/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/website/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/website/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/website/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/website/storage/upload/');
```

**/var/www/html/** - это симлинк на директорию пользователя откуда запускаются все сайты (работают нормально, не OpenCart). 
Оригинальный путь был такой: /home/user/Документы/html/, но изменил на /home/user/Documents/html/ - разницы никакой.

При открытии "**Менеджер изображений**" в админке, также файлов нет. При попытке загрузки выдает ошибку "Выберите директорию!".

Если через админку вызвать удаление кэша изображений - все удаляется, но новый кэш изображений при загрузки страницы не создается.

В исходном коде страниц (html) пути к картинкам отсутствуют.

Подозреваю, что может быть проблема как с симлинком html (всякое может быть), правами на файлы и папки (вдруг 777 неразрешено, на сервере были права 600 и 700, но пробовал на некоторых директориях и файла - не помогло), так и в установке какого-то расширения к php, если OpenCart что-то использует в этом деле.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой и может быть знает решение? (переименовывать все изображения и папки - не решение в этом случае, т.к. на реальном серваке работает и товаров более 450).

---

Заметил, что если путь **/var/www/html/** сделать реальной папкой и все что внутри (website.ocart/public_html), то картинки выводятся должным образом. Данное решение меня не устраивает и хочется, чтобы данный путь оставался симлинком.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть это не совсем верное решение, но одно из двух моих решений, которые исправляют проблему:

**Решение 1** (Подходящее для меня)
В файлах конфигурации прописываем полный путь с оригинальными каталогами (не симлинки, как сейчас в настройках)

Это строку:

```
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/image/');
```

меняем на эту

```
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/user/Documents/html/website.ocart/public_html/image/');
```

В итоге прописали полный путь без симлинков. Все работает как надо. Правда почему с симлинками так OpenCart не работает - не знаю.

Единственное, что возможно при первом обновлении страницы - сильное зависание и ошибка скрипта генерирующего изображения, т.к. создается кэш всех изображений, а их у меня было много.

**Решение 2** (не использовать симлинки)
Весь путь к директории `/var/www/html/website.ocart/public_html/` не должен содержать симлинков, иначе будет такая проблема, как в вопросе.
Если путь без симлинков, то все работает как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Типичная проблема заключается в несоответствии пути до изображения.

В скрипте **/admin/model/tool/image.php:5** стоит проверка на соответствие пути.

Допустим, в конфиге у вас прописан путь к изображениям:
**G://server/site/image/**

А в системе такой путь с учетом регистра: **G://Server/Site/image/**

В скрипте **/admin/model/tool/image.php:5**
выражение

```
if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $filename) || substr(str_replace('\\', '/',realpath(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)), 0, strlen(DIR_IMAGE)) != DIR_IMAGE) {
    return;
}
```

в условии всегда будет равно `TRUE`

У меня лично исправлено так:

```
if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $filename) || strtolower(substr(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)), 0, strlen(DIR_IMAGE))) != strtolower(DIR_IMAGE)) {
    return;
}
```